# How do I handle C-style comments in Ruby using Parslet?

Tags: ruby, parsing, peg, parslet

Taking as a starting point the code example from the [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/)'s own creator (available in this [link](https://github.com/kschiess/parslet/blob/master/example/comments.rb)) I need to extend it so as to retrieve all the non-commented text from a file written in a C-like syntax.

The provided example is able to successfully parse C-style comments, treating these areas as regular line spaces. However, this simple example only expects 'a' characters in the non-commented areas of the file such as the input example:

```
         a
      // line comment
      a a a // line comment
      a /* inline comment */ a 
      /* multiline
      comment */
```

The rule used to detect the non-commented text is simply:

```rb
   rule(:expression) { (str('a').as(:a) >> spaces).as(:exp) }
```

Therefore, what I need is to generalize the previous rule to get all the other (non-commented) text from a more generic file such as:

```
     word0
  // line comment
   word1 // line comment
  phrase /* inline comment */ something 
  /* multiline
  comment */
```

I am new to Parsing Expression Grammars and neither of my previous trials succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea is that everything is code (aka non-comment) until one of the sequences `//` or `/*` appears. You can reflect this with a rule like this:

```
rule(:code) {
  (str('/*').absent? >> str('//').absent? >> any).repeat(1).as(:code)
}
```

As mentioned in my comment, there is a small problem with strings, though. When a comment  occurs inside a string, it obviously is part of the string. If you were to remove comments from your code, you would then alter the meaning of this code. Therefore, we have to let the parser know what a string is, and that any character inside there belongs to it. Another thing are escape sequences. For example the string `"foo \" bar /*baz*/"`, which contains a literal double quote, would actually be parsed as `"foo \"`, followed by some code again. This is of course something that needs to be addressed. I have written a complete parser that handles all of the above cases:

```
require 'parslet'

class CommentParser < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:eof) { 
    any.absent? 
  }

  rule(:block_comment_text) {
    (str('*/').absent? >> any).repeat.as(:comment)
  }

  rule(:block_comment) {
    str('/*') >> block_comment_text >> str('*/')
  }

  rule(:line_comment_text) {
    (str("\n").absent? >> any).repeat.as(:comment)
  }

  rule(:line_comment) {
    str('//') >> line_comment_text >> (str("\n").present? | eof)
  }

  rule(:string_text) {
    (str('"').absent? >> str('\\').maybe >> any).repeat
  }

  rule(:string) {
    str('"') >> string_text >> str('"')
  }

  rule(:code_without_strings) {
    (str('"').absent? >> str('/*').absent? >> str('//').absent? >> any).repeat(1)
  }

  rule(:code) {
    (code_without_strings | string).repeat(1).as(:code)
  }

  rule(:code_with_comments) {
    (code | block_comment | line_comment).repeat
  }

  root(:code_with_comments)
end
```

It will parse your input

```
     word0
  // line comment
   word1 // line comment
  phrase /* inline comment */ something 
  /* multiline
  comment */
```

to this AST

```
[{:code=>"\n   word0\n "@0},
 {:comment=>" line comment"@13},
 {:code=>"\n  word1 "@26},
 {:comment=>" line comment"@37},
 {:code=>"\n phrase "@50},
 {:comment=>" inline comment "@61},
 {:code=>" something \n "@79},
 {:comment=>" multiline\n comment "@94},
 {:code=>"\n"@116}]
```

To extract everything except the comments you can do:

```
input = <<-CODE
     word0
  // line comment
   word1 // line comment
  phrase /* inline comment */ something 
  /* multiline
  comment */
CODE

ast = CommentParser.new.parse(input)
puts ast.map{|node| node[:code] }.join
```

which will produce

```
   word0

  word1
 phrase  something
```

Comment: I edited my answer because while testing the parser with real C code, I discovered that the old parser would also remove comment-like structures inside strings, which is obviously wrong. It took a while to figure out, but now it works correctly, even with escape sequences inside the strings.

Comment: I think this will break if you end you file with a line comment, but no `\n`. You will need `rule(:eof) { any.absent? }` and change line_comment to   `rule(:line_comment) {
    str('//') >> line_comment_text >> (str("\n").present? | eof)
  }`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to handle comments is to consider them white space.  For example:

```
rule(:space?) do
  space.maybe
end

rule(:space) do
  (block_comment | line_comment | whitespace).repeat(1)
end

rule(:whitespace) do
  match('/s')
end

rule(:block_comment) do
  str('/*') >>
  (str('*/').absent >> match('.')).repeat(0) >>
  str('*/')
end

rule (:line_comment) do
  str('//') >> match('[^\n]') >> str("\n")
end
```

Then, when you are writing rules with white-space, such as this entirely off-the-cuff and probably wrong rule for C,

```
rule(:assignment_statement) do
  lvalue >> space? >> str('=') >> space? >> rvalue >> str(';')
end
```

comments get "eaten" by the parser without any fuss.  Anywhere white space can or must appear, comments of any kind are allowed, and are treated as white space.

This approach is not as suitable for your *exact* problem, which is to recognize non-comment text in a C program, but it works very well in a parser which must recognize the full language.

Comment: I thought I was crazy doing this :D

Comment: @Dorian Either you are not crazy, or you have company in your madness.